# File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import error

Tags: python, scrapy

I made a simple crawler that's supposed to get and download the images from an instagram profile but I keep getting this error message.

I tried following this tutorial https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

```
#instagarm_spider.py

class InstagramSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ig'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.instagram.com/kyliejenner/'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        image_urls = scrapy.Field()
        images = scrapy.Field()
        yield {'image_urls': image_urls,
               'images': images}
```

## settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'instagramscraper' SPIDER_MODULES = ['instagramscraper.spiders'] 

NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'instagramscraper.spiders' 

ITEM_PIPELINES = { 'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1 } 

IMAGES_STORE = 

'C:\Users\jliv3\PycharmProjects\Instagram\instagramscraper\instagramscraper\sp

iders\test'
```

Here are all the error messages I recieved.

```
 File "C:\Users\jliv3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", 

line 193, in _run_module_as_main

    "__main__", mod_spec)

  File "C:\Users\jliv3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", 

line 85, in _run_code

    exec(code, run_globals)

  File 

"C:\Users\jliv3\PycharmProjects\Instagram\venv\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py"

, line 9, in <module>

  File "c:\users\jliv3\pycharmprojects\instagram\venv\lib\site-

packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 114, in execute

    settings = get_project_settings()

  File "c:\users\jliv3\pycharmprojects\instagram\venv\lib\site-

packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
    
settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
 
 File "c:\users\jliv3\pycharmprojects\instagram\venv\lib\site-

packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 294, in setmodule
    
module = import_module(module)
  
File 

"C:\Users\jliv3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.

py", line 127, in import_module
    
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  
File 

"C:\Users\jliv3\PycharmProjects\Instagram\instagramscraper\instagramscraper\se

ttings.py", line 70
    
IMAGES_STORE = 

'C:\Users\jliv3\PycharmProjects\Instagram\instagramscraper\instagramscraper\spiders\test'
                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set your IMAGES_STORE like this:

```
IMAGES_STORE = r'C:\Users\jliv3\PycharmProjects\Instagram\instagramscraper\instagramscraper\spiders\test'
```

This way the '\U' will be treated as literal characters, which is what you need here.

Comment: It's still giving the same messages.